# Undefined columns selected when renaming columns

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I need to rename columns of a data frame, excluding the last column. This is how I do this:

```
data = as.data.frame(data )
names(data ) <- paste0('X', 1:(ncol(data )-1))
```

After executing this code I try to open the data frame `data`, and the following error message appears:

```
Error in View : undefined columns selected
```

Comment: try `names(data )[-ncol(data)] <- paste0('X', 1:(ncol(data )-1))`

Comment: Not reproducible for me using the Windows R GUI, with `df <- mtcars; names(df) <- paste0("X", 1:(ncol(df)-1)); View(df)`

Comment: @Marat Talipov: Thanks a lot. Your code solved the problem.

Comment: @Josh O'Brien: Maybe the problem was that two of my columns had the same name "50%".

Comment: Rstudio doesn't like unnamed columns. Try  `df <- data.frame(c(1,2));names(df) <- NULL; View(df)`

Answer (score 1):

The example below allows you to choose which variables to NOT rename, regardless of where they are in the data frame:

```
mydata <- mtcars
mydata = as.data.frame(mydata)
colnames <- names(mydata)
skipcols = c("carb","am")
#in your specific case: skipcols = names(mydata)[ncol(mydata)]
colnames[!colnames %in% skipcols]<- paste0("X",
                                           1:(ncol(mydata)- length(skipcols)))
names(mydata) <- colnames
[1] "X1"   "X2"   "X3"   "X4"   "X5"   "X6"
[7] "X7"   "X8"   "am"   "X9"   "carb"
```

You could make it a lot shorter if you don't care about readability.